# JqGrid - How to load rowList values dynamically from Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, jqgrid

How to add rowList tom jqGrid dynamically from the spring 3 based on the total number of rows.
Ex: If total rows are 300 and per page if we are showing only 20. So the List shall be displayed as 20,40,60, ..... 300 from the Spring controller and has to bind it to jqGrid rowList attribute.

Please if any idea share us. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In general I agree with **david**, but to be exactly the column "Can be changed?" of [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) says only that one can't use `setGridParam` method to change select values specified by `rowList` option.

To change the dropdown one have to modify the innerHTML of the `<select>` manually. For example the code

```js
$("#pager .ui-pg-selbox").append('<option role="option" value="5">5</option>' +
    '<option role="option" value="1000">All</option>');
```

I used in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicChangeOfPagerSelBox.htm) to demonstrate this. After clicking of the button "Change rowList from [10] to [10, 5, 1000]" one get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) for `rowList` you will see in the last column of the table it says "No". The header for that column is "Can be changed?". `rowList` cannot be dynamically changed according to the documentation.